# How to allow users open a page in QQ internal browser that will be redirected to a blocked page firstly?

Tags: html, nginx, qq

I written docs in [here](https://qqoyoe581hs.feishu.cn/wiki/Tvr2w0rZNiokUckmX5pcEVhBnac) and want to open it to my service users.

Because:

1. Most of my users are using QQ or WeChat (IM software) on Android, IOS or PC.
2. Clicking URLs displayed in these apps will open its internal browser, instead of system built-in browser.
3. These apps ban some URLs, clicking them won't open the page but open a page said `This website is unsafe, to open it, copy its URL and open it in other browser`.
4. I'm using docs service, `feishu`, provided by one of the competitors of QQ and WeChat, and they ban `https://login.feishu.cn`.
5. My docs can be seen by everyone, but it will be redirected to `https://login.feishu.cn` firstly, then redirect back to the content. So, my docs will be banned.
6. Recently QQ updated, added a button under the line `This website is unsafe ...` called `copy link`, but this button will only copy the error page link like `${unsafe_page}?url=${original_url}`, not the original page link. My users will find that they opened page in other browser still said my website is unsafe.

I want to make my pages open directly in the QQ internal browser instead of copying URL, quitting QQ, open another browser, paste URL and open it. I tried:

1. Use `frame` and `iframe` to render content by following codes:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="zh_CN">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2">
  <title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%">
  <frame src="https://qqoyoe581hs.feishu.cn/wiki/Tvr2w0rZNiokUckmX5pcEVhBnac"></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes>
  <body align="center">
    <p>some notice... </p>
  </body>
</noframes>
</html>
```

But the response code of getting `https://qqoyoe581hs.feishu.cn/wiki/Tvr2w0rZNiokUckmX5pcEVhBnac` will be `400`.

2. Use `proxy_pass`: pages can be open in other browsers, but it will be banned in QQ or
   WeChat internal browser because of redirecting to `login.feishu.cn`.
3. Use `iframe`: pages can be loaded but because `feishu.com` cannot process cookies, so it will be redirected to `login.feishu.cn`.

:(

Is there any way to implement it?